# Dynamic styling control using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, css

I want to style an element based on the buttons clicked like bold, italic, underline. 
So i need to pass the id of an element to the onclick function of the buttons. 
Here i am facing how to get the id of the element to onclick functions dynamically. That ID will not be static. Please suggest some idea.

HTML span element having class testClass and text "change my style". This should be some ID so that any newly created element should not change.

```
<span class="testClass">change my style </span>

     $(document).ready(function () {
        // chethan starts
        $("#btnBold").click(function () {

            $(".testClass").addClass('boldFont');
        });
```

I am using this function to change the class based on the buttons clicked.
I want to use this as a generic styling control which will appear when we clicks some button and will be able to change the style of an element using this styling control.
 Please suggest me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the id of the button by the event object.

```
// buttons is the class applied to all the clickable buttons
$(".buttons").click(function (event) {
    var button = this;
    var buttonID = $(button).attr('id');
    // buttonId is the id of the button clicked i.e `btnBold`
    $(".testClass").addClass('boldFont');
});
```

Comment: Your answer seems more nearer. But i need the id of the clicked element to be passed to jquery function in order to modify style dynamically. Here in this case i need id of the span element. That styling control will appear on click of the element to be modified.

Answer (score 1):

Just use classes and data attributes, for example create your buttons like this:

```
<a href="#" class="style-toggle" data-style="bold">Bold</a>
<a href="#" class="style-toggle" data-style="italic">Italic</a>
<a href="#" class="style-toggle" data-style="underline">Underline</a>
```

Then bind your events in jQuery like this:

```
$('.style-toggle').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $(this).toggleClass( 'active' );
  $('#element-to-style').toggleClass( $(this).data('style') );
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i understand your problem.

```
           $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#btnBold").click(function() {
                    clickMe(this, "boldFont");
                });
            });
            var clickMe = function(elem, style) {
                if (!$(elem).hasClass(style)){  
                    $(elem).addClass(style);
                }
            }
```

And you could use the "clickMe" function for all the elements you need.